# Openshift unable to connect to the server

Tags: openshift, openshift-client-tools

I am having issues with setting up Open shift and getting the following error after connecting to my server domain:

#### Command:

```
  User$ rhc setup --server=app-domain.rhcloud.com
```

#### Result:

```
The server has rejected your connection attempt with an older SSL protocol.
Pass --ssl-version=sslv3 on the command line to connect to this server.
```

I am not sure what this is telling me to do. I tried using the instruction literally and it does not recognize the command.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You should not pass rhc setup the `--server` flag unless you are running your own OpenShift Origin or OpenShift Enterprise broker.  For OpenShift Online, just run the `rhc setup` command with no other options and it will setup fine.  If that command messed up your express.conf file (which it should not have) you just need to delete your `~/.openshift/express.conf` file then run `rhc setup` again without any flags.  Basically you tried to point rhc to your gear as an OpenShift Online broker, which will not work.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have ran rhc setup and created an SSH key but it will not accept my password for it no matter how many times I enter it. It is hugely frustrating as I have been trying to connect to my application for days with no avail.

Comment: If your ssh key is working, you don't use a password, it's public key authentication.  If you set a password on your ssh key when you created it, then you will need to enter that password when it asks you for it.  Make sure you read what it says when it asks for a password and make sure which one it's asking for.

Comment: The problem is that when it asks me to upload a key it prompts me to `.Enter passphrase for /Users/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa: ` If I just click enter and enter without adding a password.

Comment: If I do this I get this error time and time again `An SSH connection could not be established to myapp-itagiba.rhcloud.com. Your SSH configuration may not be correct, or the application may not be responding. Could not parse PKey: no start line (ArgumentError)`

Comment: I cannot win if I add a password, I cannot win if I don't.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up answering this on another forum post:

The only way that this worked for me was to actually create a SSH key locally with ssh-keygen -p without rhc setup and "not" giving it a password. I then went back to OpenShift clicked add a key and pasted the contents of my rsa file.

There is obviously some kind of bug with authentication on Openshift or the installation is not right.

It would be good to find out what is going on and why does it work if I do it, this way.